# How to plot 1000 simulations in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have generated 1000 simulations by the following codes.

```
ar1 = 0.4857
ar2 = 0.0173
ma1 = -0.8054
r0 <-  0.002937432 #mean of margin.logrtn
e0 <- 0.002976873 #mean of fit.margin.logrtn$res


r.sims <- matrix(rep(0,1000*52),nrow=52, ncol=1000)
e.sims <- matrix( rnorm(52*1000, mean =  0.002976873, sd = 0.1056021), 52, 1000) 


r.sims[1] <- ar1*r0 + e.sims[1] + ma1*e0
r.sims[2] <- ar1*r.sims[1] + ar2*r0 + e.sims[2] + ma1*e.sims[1]

for(j in 1:1000) {
    for(i in 1:52) {
        if (i == 1) {
            r.sims[i,] <- r.sims[1]
        } else {
            if(i == 2) {
                r.sims[i,] <- r.sims[2]
            } else {
                if(i > 2) {
                    r.sims[i,] <- r.sims[i-1,]*ar1 + r.sims[i-2,]*ar2 + e.sims[i,] + e.sims[i-1,]*ma1
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to plot the simulations in R, I would like to create weekly dates for the simulations and plot all 1000 simulations on the same graph. I tried to export the data into excel and created dates there, and imported the data again, but I then realised I would have to create 1000 time series, that's too much typing... unless there is an easier way of doing that... can someone please help?

Many thanks!

Comment: This question is better suited in stackoverflow.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about statistics within the scope defined in the help center.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not mention what kind of plots so here is just a simple time series plot. Anyway, you can use for loop in plot command as well, unless I am missing something in your question.

```
ymax <- max(r.sims)
ymin <- min(r.sims)

plot(r.sims[,1], type="l", col="#ff000010", ylim=c(ymin, ymax))
for (i in 2:1000){
lines(r.sims[,i], type="l", col="#ff000010")
}
```

[image]

---

**EDIT:**

**Q:** Hi Just wondering if there is any way I can plot this in multiple colours? Many thanks!

**A:** Yes, you can do so by supplying an array of color codes:

```
ymax <- max(r.sims)
ymin <- min(r.sims)
color <- c(rep("#ff000010", 499), rep("#0000ff10", 500))

plot(r.sims[,1], type="l", col="#ff000010", ylim=c(ymin, ymax))
for (i in 2:1000){
lines(r.sims[,i], type="l", col=color[i])
}
```

Line three specifies the first 499 to be red and the next 500 to be blue. Then in the last line, add "col=color[i]" to apply the color scheme.

[image]

Comment: Hi Just wondering if there is any way I can plot this in multiple colours? Many thanks!

Comment: @user2707605 Yes, I put a suggested method in the answer. How to color and what to color largely depend on what you'd like to show. The example should give you some shell to work on.